# Failing to FTP with python (badly)

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to FTP a file to Juniper and I'm failing. I think it has something to do with the pasv setting but I don't know what it should be as I've tried both pasv=true and pasv=false. Help please?

```
ftp.set_pasv(False)
ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile', fileRSI)

error_perm: 500 Illegal PORT command.

ftp.set_pasv(True)
ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile', fileRSI)

error_temp: 425 Security: Bad IP connecting.
```

Answer (score 2):

> error_temp: 425 Security: Bad IP connecting.

This is a security check by vsftp that the control connection and the data connection originate at the same IP address. I assume that either

- you have a multi-homed machine (i.e. multiple IP addresses on the same interface) and python ftplib is messing something up (unlikely)
- you are trying to do FXP where the data connection and control connection are handled by different hosts (unlikely)
- there is some strange network translation going on inside your router or firewall

Comment: I got this on TravisCI: https://travis-ci.org/MartinThoma/cfg_load/jobs/554909259 - do you have any advice? Should I ask another question "Why does TravisCI give 'error_temp: 425 Security: Bad IP connecting'?"?

Comment: @MartinThoma: There is not enough context to see where this error comes from. Just linking to some output from Travis and expecting others to figure out all by themselves what the build does in the first place would make it too broad as a new question. Thus, if you ask it as a new question please add sufficient context instead of just linking to some output from Travis (which is also only available if visitors are logged into Travis).